# array difference based on positions in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have tried multiple approach to solve this problem, any heads up would be great help.
I'm having a drag and drop functionality using `ng-draggable.js` in my project,so initially I set the elements to `array A`, and when I drag and drop an element inside the array, I don’t know how to capture the changed elements in that array with positions.
say `A = [1,2,3]` now customer changes the position with drag and drop feature.
Its becomes `B = [2,1,3]`. when I do a diff of `A and B`, I must get the changed elements `[2,1]` with positions, so that I can send it to server th elements with updated positions.
I have tried `underscore.js _.difference(A,B)`, it gives me empty array,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `.difference()` returns set differences, but the index is important here:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [2,1,3];
var diff = a.filter(function(value, index) {
    return b[index] != value;
}); //[1,2]
var positions = diff.map(function(value) {
  return b.indexOf(value);
}); // [0,1]
```

Then, for each of those values you need to find the position in array `b` using `.indexOf()`

Comment: Thanks Jack, am new to learning the array manipulation concept. I know we can use b.indexOf(1) will return me position.

Comment: if I change var a = [1,2,3]; var b = [1,3,2]; it give me [2,3], how will I pass this array inside indexOf to find positions of this existing in B[]

Comment: You have to pass each value in that array to indexOf().

Comment: can you please give me the code for that, I could not get it right

Comment: Thanks a ton Jack, you  made my day. I shall go-through your code now.